# error while publishing the android app

Tags: android

I can't publish my app in my web page. Its throwing some error. I have attached screen shot of the error. Pls help me to solve this.

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRGLD.jpg)

Comment: you need to change your icon.

Comment: how about doing what the message says...

Comment: what is feature graphics Icon?

Answer (score 2):

Add Your High Resolution App Icon & Feature Graphics Icon in Play Store Publisher Account